# Why does PyMongo encode uuid.uuid1() as a BSON::Binary?

Tags: python, mongodb, uuid, pymongo, bson

I'm adding a 'GUID' key with a value of uuid.uuid1() (from python uuid module) for all my documents in Mongo. I noticed they are being stored not as strings, but as type **BSON::Binary**. I've done some Googling already, but I still don't understand what the purpose/advantage to this serialization is. Can someone explain? Should I be converting the uuid.uuid1() to strings before storing? How can I use a string to find() by the GUID value like db.myCol.find({ 'GUID' : aString })?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default serialization for a Python `uuid` uses a `UUID` binary representation in the [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) because this ensures consistent sorting for range queries, and also uses less storage for data/indexes.

For example, these three strings are equivalent in hex:

```
5d78ad35ea5f11e1a183705681b29c47
5D78AD35EA5F11E1A183705681B29C47
5d78ad35ea5f11e1A183705681B29C47
```

..but have different sort orders as strings:

```
> db.uuidsort.find().sort({_id:1})
{ "_id" : "5D78AD35EA5F11E1A183705681B29C47" }
{ "_id" : "5d78ad35ea5f11e1A183705681B29C47" }
{ "_id" : "5d78ad35ea5f11e1a183705681b29c47" }
```

Comparing the bson sizes:

```
> db.uuidtest.find()
{ "_id" : BinData(3,"XXitNepfEeGhg3BWgbKcRw==") }
{ "_id" : "5d78ad35ea5f11e1a183705681b29c47" }

> Object.bsonsize(db.uuidtest.findOne({_id: BinData(3,"XXitNepfEeGhg3BWgbKcRw==")}))
31

> Object.bsonsize(db.uuidtest.findOne({_id: "5d78ad35ea5f11e1a183705681b29c47"}))
47
```

If you do want to insert as strings, you can use [UUID.hex](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID.hex) to get the 32-character string equivalent:

```
>>> db.uuidtest.insert({'_id': uuid.hex})
'5d78ad35ea5f11e1a183705681b29c47'
```

If you want to find UUIDs by string from Python, you can use the [uuid.UUID](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID) methods:

```
>>> db.uuidtest.find_one({'_id':uuid.UUID('5d78ad35ea5f11e1a183705681b29c47')})
{u'_id': UUID('5d78ad35-ea5f-11e1-a183-705681b29c47')}
```

If you want to find UUIDs by string from the `mongo` shell, there is a `UUID()` helper:

```
> db.uuidtest.find({_id:UUID('5d78ad35ea5f11e1a183705681b29c47')})
{ "_id" : BinData(3,"XXitNepfEeGhg3BWgbKcRw==") }
```

Note: there are a few other UUID subtypes available for interoperability with other driver versions, as described in the [API docs for bson.binary](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/binary.html).

Comment: What is BinData and what do it's 2 arguments represent?

Comment: @yourfriendzak: Do you mean from the shell or from Python?  Added an example from the mongo shell.

Comment: BinData is a BSON type (see [bsonspec.org](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification)). The arguments represent the subtype (eg `3` is the old default UUID format; newer drivers default to `4`) for the encoding.  The subtype allows drivers to correct decode the binary.

Comment: Also, I noticed that str( mongoDoc['GUID'] ) also works where GUID : a BSON:UUID

Comment: @yourfriendzak: Updated with python example :)