# Error getting MongoDB by _Id in Flask

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I can query my MongoDB and I see the "_id" value like this:

```
"_id" : BinData(3,"sFgVQWMKzUiWl5dql62j2g==")
```

Using Flask 0.10.1 and PyMongo 3.0.3 I attempt to "find_one" like this:

```
record = db.collection.find_one({'_id': ObjectId("sFgVQWMKzUiWl5dql62j2g==")})
```

And I get this error:

```
bson.errors.InvalidId: 'sFgVQWMKzUiWl5dql62j2g==' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing _id as bindata and trying to retrive it as ObjectId,
instead of ObjectId.

First you need to convert your base64string to binary and then try to search.

```
bi = binary.Binary("sFgVQWMKzUiWl5dql62j2g==");
record = db.collection.find_one({'_id': bi});
```

This will work for you.
It will convert your id to binary  then compare to get result.

Comment: I get an unresolved referece when I use BinData, where is BinData located in PyMongo?

Comment: which python "binary" package is this?  I installed binary using pip but that doesn't have any Binary function,

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 record = db.collection.find_one({'_id': BinData(3, "sFgVQWMKzUiWl5dql62j2g==")})
```

Comment: I get an unresolved referece when I use BinData, where is BinData located in PyMongo?

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is how I got this working. From my PyMongo client I queried the result and got this:

```
_id: "497ffaf0-5ed3-3a4e-99ae-6b5c5f9b431e"
```

Note how that is not like the MongoDB console client which returns this:

```
_id : BinData(3,"sFgVQWMKzUiWl5dql62j2g==")
```

So seeing that the value looked like a GUID [I started digging around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12031574/74071) and found that is a UUID and with that I did this:

```
import uuid
record = db.collection.find_one({'_id': uuid.UUID("497ffaf0-5ed3-3a4e-99ae-6b5c5f9b431e")})
```

This worked! Hazzah.

Answer (score 0):

Using Flask, MongoEngine I also was receiving errors searching by _id: `mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: "DBRef('m_turk', ObjectId('5966b478b929570647f51a5c'))" is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string`

In my case, the `object id` from `MongoEngine.Document` is of type `bson.dbref.DBREF`, whereas `MongoEngine.Document` expects type `bson.objectid.ObjectId`, despite returning `bson.dbref.DBREF` on `MongoEngine.Document.objects(...).*`. I'm not sure if this is an API inconsistency or simply my fault.

The fix was:

```
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

... set Flask up ...

db = MongoEnginee(app)

class MiniFoo(db.Document):
       foo = db.StringField()

class MyDoc(db.Docment):
       key = db.StringField()
       myself = db.ReferenceField(MiniFoo)
       other_foos = db.ReferenceField(MiniFoo)

 myobj = MyDoc.objects.get(key="over the rainbow")
 # want to find other foos!

 # Will fail with exception above
 try:
     MiniFoo.objects.with_id(myobj.other_foos[0].id)
 except:
     MiniFoo.objects.with_id(ObjectId(obj.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

with **MongoEngine**

```
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

db = MongoEngine()
db.init_app(app)

class Model(db.Document):
    _id = db.ObjectIdField()
    name = db.StringField(required=True)

    @classmethod
    def findById(cls, _id: str):
        return cls.objects(_id=ObjectId(_id)).first()

modelById = Model.findById('601ec2d13ad7559bf7ebad76')
```